Why does Geoname API not geocode places which I can find on their website?
I am using the Geonames API to geocode place names and have some odd cases where the API does not give me geodata for a place that I can find on their website. I am aware that Geonames has different feature classes, and I loop through the most relevant ones in Python. Still, a few not so very unusual city names do not retrieve results.
One such case is Ahrenfeld in Lower Saxony, which I can find as a "P" feature via the search interface:
https://www.geonames.org/search.html?q=ahrenfeld&country=
The only explanation I have for the Geonames API not giving me the geodata is that an Austrian place with a-umlaut comes up as the first search result for "Ahrenfeld" and that the API may ignore this place because it is obviously not an exact string match, while not moving on to the second entry, which would be the correct one.
I tried to find more information on how exactly the API selects results but was not able to answer this question. One solution for my problem could be to change the Python code to force the API to consider more results than the top one, which seems to be the default setting now. I will try to adjust the "maxRows" parameter now and post again if it is successful. According to the Geonames Web Service documentation, the default is "10", but I am only getting one result at present.
Other suggestions are also welcome.
